# How to shorten a file in the terminal

Tags: files

I saved a python file in my desktop and want to run it in the terminal, but everytime I run it I have to type ' python /home/m3gn/Desktop/ex1.py'
Is there anyway to shorten this so that I only have to type 'python ex.1'?

Thank you!

Comment: You can `cd` into /home/m3gn/Desktop first and then run `python ex1`

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a bin folder inside your home directory: `/home/m3gn/bin` Ubuntu in theory can add this directory to your path automatically.
2. Give the python file executable permissions, that is: `chmod +x ex1.py`
3. Move the ex1.py file to the `home/m3gan/bin` directory
4. You should be able to run the file by using only the filename: `ex1.py`
5. As a plus, since Ubuntu adds bin to your path, you will have bash completion, that is if you type e + TAB or ex + TAB or ex1 + TAB, the terminal will auto complete the rest of the filename.

If Ubuntu does not automatically add bin to your path, you can manually add it at your `.bashrc` file by adding the following lines:

```
if [ -d ~/bin ] ; then
    PATH=$PATH:~/bin
fi
```

Save and close `.bashrc` and issue: `source .bashrc` in terminal, it should be ok and ready for use.

Comment: Good answer, however as well as marking it as executable with 'chmod +x', isn't it also necessary to add a 'shebang' at the top of the file telling the system use the python interpreter? e.g. '#!/usr/bin/env python'

Comment: That is correct and may or may not be the case since the OP does not provide the source which may or may not include a shebang, good observation.

Answer (score 0):

Add variable

```
ex1="/home/m3gn/Desktop/ex1.py"
```

to your `~/.bashrc`  file and run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can just use

```
python $ex1
```